# BMX: Training routine for a beginner?

Tags: training, racing, bmx

At the ripe old age of 20, I finally moved to an area with a BMX track, so this summer I'm finally going to be able to follow my life-long dream of racing. Other than spending a lot of time riding daily and practicing on my home track, what other sort of training should I be doing? What muscles do I need to work, and what's an effective way of doing so (preferably without gym equipment)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Off-bike? You might try out [plyometric exercises](http://www.sport-fitness-advisor.com/plyometricexercises.html). Plyometrics can help you improve your agility and power. In addition, you'd probably want to work on core strength.

I think that plyometrics would be helpful since BMX races are relatively short and rely a lot on agility and sprinting power.

You also mention that the track is too muddy for riding. So, you could do sprint [intervals](http://www.cptips.com/intervl.htm) on pavement. Sprint intervals will improve your stamina and speed. An example would be something like this:

- Ride easy for 10 minutes
- Sprint for 30 seconds and work your way up to 2 minute sprints
- Ride at a comfortable pace for 3 minutes
- Repeat the sprint/comfortable pace cycle 4 to 6 times
- Finish up by riding at an easy pace for another 10 minutes
- Do this 2 or at most 3 times a week but NOT on consecutive days

Comment: Thanks a lot - intervals sounds like a great idea - something that I could do today, even. I'll look into plyometric exercises, too.

Answer (score 1):

Start out by riding at low gears (Easy ones) and build stamina and basic heart endurance.
Slowly raise the gears you are using (Slowly = months/years)

Comment: Sounds good. Any suggestions for stuff that I could do off-bike? The track's been soaked all week. :P